# Chat search doesn't like apostrophes

Tags: bug, chat, search

Trying to search for words with ' characters in them in chat seems to return odd results.

For example searching for you're in the DMZ gives [results that are all oneboxes](https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=you%27re&user=&room=151) .This seems to happen with any words that have an apostrophe in them.

It doesn't appear to be just stripping the ' characters and returning results for that as hel'lo returns no results where hello obviously does, also [we're](https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=we%27re&user=&room=151) and [were](https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=were&user=&room=151) return different results.

Adding " characters round the search query doesn't seem to affect the results.

Comment: Chat search is... weird. It always was. Want another example? Try searching for the word "the". You won't get any results. :/